# An Update on my TileMap Class

Tags: java, game, file

I'm making a old-school Final Fantasy type game and I made a tile map class a while back and posted it on here ([Is this a good way to implement a tile map from a text file?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69213/is-this-a-good-way-to-implement-a-tile-map-from-a-text-file)) But, when I got to collision, it was a nightmare. So I've updated it to make it more collision friendly and I was wondering what the community's thoughts were on this code.

Tile.java

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Tile 
{
    public int texKey;  //number to represent texture
    public BufferedImage texture;
    public boolean collidable;

    public Tile(int texKey, BufferedImage texture, boolean collidable)
    {
        this.texKey = texKey;
        this.texture = texture;
        this.collidable = collidable;
    }
}
```

TileMaker.java

```
import com.stardust.rpgtest2.gfx.Assets;

public class TileMaker 
{
    public Tile[] tileArray= new Tile[28];

    public TileMaker()
    {

    }

    public void setTile()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= tileArray.length; i++)
        {                 
            switch(i)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    tileArray[i] = new Tile(i, Assets.grass, false);
                    break;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    tileArray[i] = new Tile(i, Assets.dirt, false);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    tileArray[i] = new Tile(i, Assets.water, false);
                    break;
                }
                //this goes up to 27 at the moment
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public Tile[] getTileArray()
    {
        return tileArray;
    }
}
```

TileMap.java

```
import com.stardust.rpgtest2.Game;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TileMap 
{
    int posX, posY, x, y, sx, sy, mapSize;
    public String filename;

    public int[][] tilemap;


    public TileMap(int posX, int posY, int mapSize, String filename)
    {
        this.mapSize = mapSize;
        tilemap = new int[mapSize][mapSize];
        this.posX = posX;
        this.posY = posY;
        this.sx = mapSize;
        this.sy = mapSize;
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < tilemap.length; y++)
        {       
            for(int x = 0; x < tilemap.length; x++)
            {
                int textureType = tilemap[x][y];
                BufferedImage texture = Game.tileMaker.getTileArray()[textureType].texture; 
                g.drawImage(texture, posX, posY, null);
                posY += 32;
            }
            posX += 32;
            posY = Game.mapY;
        }
        posX = Game.mapX;
        posY = Game.mapY;
    }

    public void fileParser() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        String line;

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] values = line.split(",");

            for(String str : values)
            {
                int str_int = Integer.parseInt(str);
                tilemap[x][y] = str_int;
                ++y;
            }
            ++x;
            y = 0;
        }
        x = 0;

        in.close();
    }
}
```

I call the `TileMaker.setTile()` and `TileMap.fileParser()` methods both in the initialization method in the main game class, and everything behaves as needed so far.

Comment: Updated Code http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84868/update-on-tilemap-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The [for-case paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence) is an anti-pattern, you shouldn't use it. One alternative would be to initialize the array in a static block (without for-switch), another would be to use an enum. I would prefer the second approach. Both approaches would save you the call of `TileMaker.setTile()`.
- Your indent style is not customary in Java, and it's always best to go with what most programmers of a language are used to (opening curly bracket on the same line).
- Your variable names are not very clear. What is the difference between `posX` and `x`? And what is `sx`?
- Get rid of unused fields. If you don't need `mapSize`, don't save it.
- Move magic numbers out of your code into static fields.
- I would create a separate class for the parsing of the file.

Comment: Question edited to explain posX, x, sx, and mapSize.

Comment: @Twiggy Your comments explaining your variable names are quite good, but it would be even better to just simplify your code. `sx` for example could be called `mapSizeX`. And `x` and `y` don't seem to be needed as fields at all, so they shouldn't be declared as fields, but as loop variables. I'll still revert your edit, see [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)